# Пропустить итерацию нескольких элементов или как удалить

Tags: c#, linq, htmlagilitypack

Есть такая таблица (пример, в реале количество столбцов может быть разным):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">1</td>
        <td>Название</td>
        <td class="text-blue">Название</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="">Тест</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
        <td>Название2</td>
        <td class="text-blue">Название2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="">Тест2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="uc-discip-group text-center">НАЗВАНИЕ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td>55</td><td>Программное обеспечение</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr><td>55</td><td>Экономике</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr><td>55</td><td>Технологии</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Я использую `HtmlAgilityPack` для разбора html-элементов.

Написал такой код:

```
var nodes = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-condensed']/tbody");

foreach (var table in nodes)
{
    foreach (var row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
    {
        foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
        {
            // какое-то действие..
        }
    }
}
```

Но у меня, ни в какую не получается исключить данный код:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="uc-discip-group text-center">НАЗВАНИЕ</td>
</tr>
<tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td>55</td><td>Программное обеспечение</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr><td>55</td><td>Экономике</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr><td>55</td><td>Технологии</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr>
```

Можно, конечно, заморочиться с регулярными выражениями, но мне кажется, можно и без них обойтись.

Может быть можно, как-то узнать, позицию последних элементов `tr` и использовать `LINQ`?

Я попробовал использовать `Skip`, но в него нужно передать номер элемента, а выяснить не удалось.

**UPD:**

В этой строке:

```
<tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td>55</td><td>Программное обеспечение</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr><td>55</td><td>Экономике</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr><td>55</td><td>Технологии</td><td class="text-blue">Тест</td><td>1</td><td class=""></td></tr>
```

Неизвестно сколько может быть `tr`, поэтому, варианты как с `Skip/Take` не подходят.

Comment: чисто как превдокод `foreach (var row in table.SelectNodes("tr").TakeWhile(r=>r.SelectNodes("td").Count() > 2))`

Comment: В `.Skip()` (если мы говорим о Linq) передаётся количество элементов, которое нужно пропустить. Можно посчитать количество элементов и взять `.Take()` на два меньше.

Comment: @tym32167,
@AK, я не учел, что строк с `tr` может быть неизвестным количеством (обновил первый пост).

Comment: @tym32167, ой, я тупанул, извиняюсь. У меня в исходных данных оказывается была вторая таблица и она меня путала. Ваш код рабочий, спасибо большое!

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас не валидный html. `</tr>` (закрывающих) тегов больше, чем `<tr>` (открывающих)

Comment: Я не знаю, как это работает в `HtmlAgility`, но я когда-то использовал `XPath`, и там можно написать селектор, который может вернуть все `<tr></tr>` теги до определенного тега. Тут по разметке видно, что вам нужно выбрать все `tr`-теги до определенного тега `tr`, в котором лежит `td`-тег `НАЗВАНИЕ`.

Comment: А, там как раз он и используется :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно всего лишь изменить селектор. Селектор будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var xPathSelector = @"//table[@class='table table-bordered table-condensed']/tbody/tr/td[text()='НАЗВАНИЕ']/parent::tr/preceding::tr"
var nodes = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xPathSelector);
```

Он найдет вам все элементы `tr` до элемента `td` с текстом "НАЗВАНИЕ". Краткое пояснение:

- `td[text()='НАЗВАНИЕ']` - находим элемент `td`, текст которого равен
  `НАЗВАНИЕ`.
- `parent::tr` - находим ближайший тег-родитель `tr` для тега `td`
- `preceding::tr`  - находим все теги `tr` на одном и том же уровне, которые предшествуют текущему тегу `tr`

Проверять написанные вами XPath-селекторы можно с помощью браузера Mozila Firefox (если есть в Google Chrome - напишите в комментарии об этом, пожалуйста). Перейдя на нужную страницу, нажимаете `F12` и во вкладке `Инспектор` в строке поиска вводите XPath селектор